# How to read data from .txt files with irregular white spaces (also used in the variable names)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to download the data from this [link](https://www.bls.gov/cpi/tables/relative-importance/2019.txt), a txt file with each row starting with names of the variables (containing white space), and a couple of white spaces separating the names with actual data. Here are the first few rows:

```
All items............................................   100.000        100.000     
                                                                                    
  Food and beverages..................................    14.794         16.246     
   Food...............................................    13.771         15.343     
                                                                              
    Food at home......................................     7.579          8.746     
     Cereals and bakery products......................      .984          1.124     
      Cereals and cereal products.....................      .301           .366     
       Flour and prepared flour mixes.................      .040           .051
```

I tried several options, e.g. specifying '\t' as the limiters with `read_csv`, and a few fancy options copied from other Q&As, and none works. Either the data get dropped off or the variable names get interpreted as data and I get too many columns.

How should I read this file into df in pandas?

Comment: If you're using pandas you could try a fixed width table (pandas.read_fwf)

Answer (score 1):

Read your file with `pandas.read_fwf`. The `widths` argument correspond to the widths of text that will form every column.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_fwf("myfile.txt", widths=[54, 10, 15], header=None)
print(df)
```

which gives:

```
                                                   0        1        2
0  All items........................................  100.000  100.000
1                                                NaN      NaN      NaN
2  Food and beverages...............................   14.794   16.246
3  Food.............................................   13.771   15.343
4                                                NaN      NaN      NaN
5  Food at home.....................................    7.579    8.746
6  Cereals and bakery products......................    0.984    1.124
7   Cereals and cereal products.....................    0.301    0.366
8    Flour and prepared flour mixes.................    0.040    0.051
```